# AngularJS 2 with ASPNET MVC 5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular

Is it possible to reference AngularJS 2 (alpha version) in a ASP.NET MVC project? I tried referencing the following

```
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

but still I get :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

and I am loading my controller after loading AngularJS 2

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('navigationcontroller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        { name: 'Jani', country: 'Norway' },
        { name: 'Hege', country: 'Sweden' },
        { name: 'Kai', country: 'Denmark' }
    ];
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You js code is compliant with Angular 1.x. 2 Does not have concept of scope. Module creation is different. Please read a Angular2 tutorial

Comment: @Chandermani thanks.